# Proxmox iSCSI Boot?

Tags: iscsi, proxmox

Does anyone know how to install Proxmox over iSCSI so that it can be booted over the network? My current solution is to use USB flash drives, but would like a different solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for iPXE. Create a host that mounts your Proxmox media via whatever means, then have new instances PXE boot and pull it. [This looks like a promising start.](https://github.com/morph027/pve-iso-2-pxe)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and Proxmox gives the error of not being able to find the Proxmox VE ISO.

Comment: Did you troubleshoot that at all? If so how? What errors did you get? What were you seeing?

Comment: Didn't really troubleshoot it. I will look into it. Thanks!